# Spring-Data-Solr How to provide authentication data

Tags: spring-data-solr

how do i proivde authentication data for spring data solr server?
Here is what i have in configuration

```
 <solr:solr-server id="solrServer" url="http://xxxxxxxx:8983/solr" />

  <bean id="solrTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.solr.core.SolrTemplate" scope="singleton">
    <constructor-arg ref="solrServer" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="searchRepository" class="com.bankofamerica.atmtech.repository.SolrJournalRepository">
    <property name="solrOperations" ref="solrTemplate" />
  </bean>

   <bean id="App" class="App">
    <property name="repo" ref="searchRepository" />
  </bean>
```

I don't see any property where i can set it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set `Credentials` directly but have to go through the factory.

```
@Bean
SolrTemplate solrTemplate() {
  return new SolrTemplate(solrServerFactory());
}

@Bean
SolrServerFactory solrServerFactory() {

  Credentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials("foo", "bar");
  return new HttpSolrServerFactory(solrServer(), "collection1", credentials , "BASIC");
}

@Bean
SolrServer solrServer() {
  return new HttpSolrServer("http://localhost:8983/solr");
}
```

I guess some kind of `SolrAuthenticationProvider` picked up and applied if present in application context would make sense in this case.